# Why Form.Close wait MessageBox.Show?

Tags: c#, winforms, synchronization, begininvoke, invokerequired

look this please:

```cs
var form = new Form();

form.Shown += (_, __) =>
{
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 1000 };

    timer.Tick += (x, xx) =>
    {
        timer.Stop();
        GC.KeepAlive(timer);
        timer.Dispose();

        form.Close();

        Application.DoEvents(); // no effect 

        // it will cause form keep show
        MessageBox.Show("asdf");

        // but if this, that's fine
        // BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("asdf")));
    };

    timer.Start();
};

form.ShowDialog();
```

`form.Close` before `MessageBox.Show`, but `form` will not close until close msgBox, please help.

--end--

all in code, why need more words? all in code, why need more words? all in code, why need more words?

Comment: `Close();` != `return;`

Comment: Note that, in this code, you're in the same context that started `form`: `Application.DoEvents();` won't affect the *special* message loop generated when you call `Form.ShowDialog()`. The `WM_Close` message will be processed when the method exits. Different from `Form.Hide()` (same as  `Form.Visible = false`), where the Window's destiny will be decided somewhere else. When you `BeginInvoke()`, the `ThreadMethodEntry` that holds the Delegate (Action or MethodInvoker), will be enqueued, causing it to execute after (through PostMessage).

Comment: Btw, it's not clear what you need help with.

Comment: @Jimi but if use `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_=>MessageBox.Show("asdf"), null)`, it's still block window close. I know `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post` use `Control.BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you show a form as modal using `ShowDialog()`, calling `Close` in fact sends a `WM_CLOSE` message and then it sets `DialogResult` to `Cancel` which acts as a flag for modal message loop to exit the loop.

So `Close` will not close or hide the modal dialog immediately. Then after finishing the modal message loop, the modal dialog will be hide (but not destroyed).

`MessageBox` method also blocks the execution of code, so codes after the message box will execute just after closing the message box. So now it's clear why after calling `Close`, first the `MessageBox` shows then after closing message box, form closes.

Just to make it easier to understand, here is a pseudo-code which shows what is happening when you call `ShowDialog` in your code:

```
Form Shows
While Form.DialogResult != None
{
    Form.Close → Sends WM_CLOSE → Sets Form.DialogResult = Cancel 
    MessageBox.Show and wait until MessageBox closes
}
Form Hides
```

Just keep in mind, `Close` is not equal to `return`, it means the code which you have after `Close` will run as well. Here the code is `MessageBox` which blocks the loop until after `MessageBox` closes.

To hide the dialog immediately, replace the `form.Close()` with `form.Hide()`, this way without waiting for the loop, you are commanding the form to get hidden. But it doesn't mean the `form` has been closed and therefore lines of code which you have after `ShowDialog` will not run until after the loop finishes.

For more information about how `Close` and `ShowDialog` work, you may want to take a look at a Windows Forms source code, specially the following lines:

- [`LocalModalMessageLoop` in `Application`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,3560)
- [`CheckCloseDialog` in `Form`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,9e5ff82765459e00)
- [`WMClose` in `Form`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,835f7070c7e52263)